# Sextante (SAGA) "Normalisation" problem

Tags: qgis, raster, sextante-qgis-plugin

I don't understand the SAGA-module "NORMALISATION". In SAGA Gis I just can define one MIN and one MAX value. In QGis I have to define 2 of both. How to handle that exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Some sextante plugins dont work properly. You enter which MIN and MAX values but it doesnt matter... It always normalize data between 0 and 1. This problem happens only working with Sextante in QGIS. But works correctly in SAGA.

Comment: Please file a bug-report then. It is not easy to overlook all the geoalgorithms for possible bugs and i am sure the SEXTANTE developer will appreciate the report